# Angular 2. event that fires once a list has loaded into DOM

Tags: angular

In my Angular 2 app, I have a component that basically has a list with an 
In part of my template I have list that will be populated from a service.

> `<div class="column" *ngFor="#item of availableList >..`

In my component I have a 'load' method that grabs data from a service and assigns the data to this 'associatedList' variable. IE:

```
loadAssets() {
        this.someService.loadData().subscribe( data => {
                this.associatedList = data;
            }
        }
```

at this point I need a listener that fires when the data has been loaded into the template and the items actually exist in the DOM. Can anyone help me out here ?
THANKS!

Comment: I have the same question and so far I could not find a perfect solution for this. A dirty fix was to use ```setTimeout``` in the ```complete:``` within the ```subscribe```. Basically when the data arrives and the subscription completes, I waited for 500ms so the data gets loaded into the DOM. I hope there are better solutions out there and I am keen to here what you and others finally did!

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to implement the AfterViewInit interface:

https://angular.io/api/core/AfterViewInit

Comment: this fires when the original dom loads, but not after items get loaded. I tried in this method to no avail.

Answer (score -1):

Try these... You need OnInit

https://angular.io/api/core/OnInit

https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks

#### Update:

With the description there might be two more things that you can do. One you can try AfterViewChecked instead of Init but with some checks I doubt it might be of any help. You might want to check AfterViewChecked lifecycle hook. Or alternatively you can create your own custom flag that is triggered to truthy after this line `this.associatedList = data;`. This flag can then be captured/checked using the AfterViewChecked (Preferred) /OnChanges life cycle hook to do your logic and then reset to false after your logic. May be this should help.

Ofcourse you can create an custom observable but that just be a little too much of an overdo...